# MongoDB aggregate, how to addToSet each element of array in group pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, each

I have documents that contains a tags fields. It's a simple array with tag names inside, no object nor _id inside.
Just plain tags like this `["Protocol", "Access", "Leverage", "Capability"]`.

And in my group pipeline I tried something like `'selectedTags': { $addToSet: '$tags' }` but then I end up with an array containing arrays of tags. And I get the same with `$push`.

I tried to use `$each` or `$pushAll` but they are not supported as grouping operator as my shell tell me.

Can someone help me on this one please ?

Thank you

Edit:

Sample docs:

```
{
    "_id" : "HWEdDGsq86x4ikDSQ",
    "teamId" : "AdLizGnPuqbWNsFHe",
    "ownerId" : "Qb5EigWjqn2t3bfxD",
    "type" : "meeting",
    "topic" : "Grass-roots hybrid knowledge user",
    "fullname" : "Guidouil",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-30T09:00:05.513Z"),
    "shareResults" : true,
    "open" : true,
    "language" : "fr",
    "tags" : [
        "Protocol",
        "Challenge",
        "Artificial Intelligence",
        "Capability"
    ],
    "isDemo" : true,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-15T19:24:05.513Z"),
    "participantsCount" : 10,
    "ratersCount" : 10,
    "averageRating" : 3.4,
    "hasAnswers" : true,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-15T19:24:05.562Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "rXvkFndpXwJ6KAvNo",
    "teamId" : "AdLizGnPuqbWNsFHe",
    "ownerId" : "Qb5EigWjqn2t3bfxD",
    "type" : "meeting",
    "topic" : "Profit-focused modular system engine",
    "fullname" : "Guidouil",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T12:00:05.564Z"),
    "shareResults" : true,
    "open" : true,
    "language" : "fr",
    "tags" : [
        "Initiative",
        "Artificial Intelligence",
        "Protocol",
        "Utilisation"
    ],
    "isDemo" : true,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-15T19:24:05.564Z"),
    "participantsCount" : 33,
    "ratersCount" : 33,
    "averageRating" : 2.9393939393939394,
    "hasAnswers" : true,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-15T19:24:05.753Z")
}
```

Aggregation:

```
db.surveys.aggregate(
  { $match: query },
  {
    $group: {
      '_id': {
        'year': { $year: '$startDate' },
        'day': { $dayOfYear: '$startDate' },
      },
      'participants': { $sum: '$ratersCount' },
      'rating': { $avg: '$averageRating' },
      'surveys': { $push: '$_id' },
      'selectedTags': { $addToSet: '$tags' },
      'peoples': { $addToSet: '$fullname' },
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
);
```

then I tried to change the selectedTags to `{ $push: { $each: '$tags' } }` or `{ $pushAll: '$tags' }` but this does not execute :(

**Edit 2:**

In javascript I do it like that:

```
return Surveys.aggregate(
  { $match: query },
  { $group: {
    _id: dateGroup,
    participants: { $sum: '$ratersCount' },
    rating: { $avg: '$averageRating' },
    surveys: { $push: '$_id' },
    selectedTags: { $push: '$tags' },
    peoples: { $addToSet: '$fullname' },
  } },
  { $project: {
    _id: null,
    selectedTags: {
      $reduce: {
        input: "$selectedTags",
        initialValue: [],
        in: { $setUnion: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
      }
    },
  } }
);
```

Comment: Could you show your attempts? It might shed some light on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To mimic functionality of [$addToSet update operator with $each modifier](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html#each-modifier) in aggregation pipeline you can use a combination of [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) on grouping stage and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce) + [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion) on projection stage. E.g.:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group:{
       _id: null,
       selectedTags: { $push: '$tags' }      
    }},
    {$project: {
        selectedTags: { $reduce: {
            input: "$selectedTags",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {$setUnion : ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

results with a single document which contains a distinct list of tags from all documents in `selectedTags` array.

Comment: You are right, I'm getting closer to what I want, now I have an array containing an array of tags.  Like this : `SelectedTags : [ ["Leverage", "Utilisation", "Capability", "Initiative"] ]`

Comment: How? The snippet in the answer returns a flat array of tag.

Comment: I still need the other fields, so I did this

Comment: hmm, other fields don't matter really. Just replace `selectedTags: { $push: '$tags' }` in group stage, and project it with the expression I posted. Leave the rest fields as needed.

Comment: I tried this https://gist.github.com/guidouil/147774bc36d0d62e1376eedaa1b54ff0 and it looks like it just returns me the original group part

Comment: Dear @Guidouil, please avoid external links. Include all the information within the question itself in the future. The nested array must be coming from javascript library you are using. I tried your query in mongodb shell and got a flat `SelectedTags` array per group. As a side note, you probably want to include rest of the fields in the projection stage. Otherwise you are losing them.

Comment: You are right, my issue was linked to javascript library I'm using : Meteor. Currently it's on MongoDB 3.2 and it doesn't have reduce. I found a workaround to get it connected to a mongo 3.4 and now everything is great thanks to you. Merci beaucoup Alex

Comment: If you don't want to lose all other fields, you may want to use `$addFields` instead of `$project`

Answer (score 21):

You can also use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to get result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$tags"},
  {$group:{
     _id: null,
     selectedTags: { $addToSet: '$tags' }      
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super simple!

Comment: This is an clean elegant looking solution. Memory usage is a real concern at the `unwind tags` stage though.

Answer (score 0):

Dannyxu and Alex Beck's answers both worked, but only partially when used with a group stage. I needed to combine both to get the desired result of a single flat array of tags:

```
Model.aggregate()
        .match({ /** some query */ })
        .group({
            _id: '$teamId',
            tagsSet: { $push: '$tags' },
            numRecords: { $sum: 1 },
        })
        .project({
            _id: 0,
            numRecords: 1,
            tagsSet: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: '$tagsSet',
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $setUnion: ['$$value', '$$this'] },
                },
            },
        })
        .unwind({ path: '$tagsSet' })
        .group({
            _id: null,
            selectedTags: { $addToSet: '$tagsSet' },
            numRecords: { $sum: '$numRecords' },
        })
```