# How to merge an array field in multiple documents into a single output array in MongoDB and mongoexport to csv

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate

I have a MongoDB collection, Groups. Each group has an array of members, referenced by the member's unique id. A user can be a member of many groups.

Group data looks like this:

```
{ _id: 1, members: ['1', '3', '5'], status: 'active' }
{ _id: 2, members: ['4', '1', '10', '11'], status: 'inactive' }
{ _id: 3, members: ['1', '2', '9'], status: 'active' }
```

I'm trying to extract all members of active groups as a single array of member ids, without duplication. I want to export them to a csv file using mongoexport.

I can export the ids of the relevant projects and their member lists:

```
mongoexport -h localhost:3001 --db mydbname --collection groups --type=csv --fields _id,members --query '{"status": "active"}' --out mongotestoutput.txt
```

But I can't figure out how to merge the member lists into a single array. I've been looking at [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) but I'm just getting lost among all the different options, I can't see which one would do what I need. Very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation with `$unwind` and then `$out` to create a new collection that looks like you need. Then export this new collection to CSV file.

```
db.test1.insertMany([
  { _id: 1, members: ['1', '3', '5'], status: 'active' },
  { _id: 2, members: ['4', '1', '10', '11'], status: 'inactive' },
  { _id: 3, members: ['9'], status: 'active' }
])
```

`{_id:0}` here and below is used to suppress _id field

```
db.test1.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$members"},
  {$project:{_id:0}},
  {$out:"test2"}
])


db.test2.find({},{_id:0})
{ "members" : "1", "status" : "active" }
{ "members" : "3", "status" : "active" }
{ "members" : "5", "status" : "active" }
{ "members" : "4", "status" : "inactive" }
{ "members" : "1", "status" : "inactive" }
{ "members" : "10", "status" : "inactive" }
{ "members" : "11", "status" : "inactive" }
{ "members" : "9", "status" : "active" }
```

Or if you need to get members by status in the array - add another `$group`, `$addToSet` stage:

```
db.test1.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$members"},
  {$project:{_id:0}},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$status", members:{$addToSet:"$members"} } },
  {$out:"test3"}
])

db.test3.find()
{ "_id" : "inactive", "members" : [ "4", "1", "10", "11" ] }
{ "_id" : "active", "members" : [ "1", "3", "5", "9" ] }
```

See [**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yKHtz6Dup9a)

Comment: The result I want is ['1', '3', '5', '9'], that is a single array of all users who are members of an active group. I think your answer is giving something else.

Comment: Then just another aggregation step: `{ "$group": { "_id": "$status", members:{$push:"$members"} }`. I'll update the answer

Comment: Hmm, no, I'm still seeing one output doc per input doc, not a single array combining members from different groups. Unwind and group both seem to me like they only act on a single document, they don't seem to combine values from many documents?

Comment: Hmm... I thought `{ "_id" : "active", "members" : [ "1", "3", "5", "9" ] }` is exactly the line that you are looking for. See Mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6YyjrORziD

Comment: Thank you for the link to mongoplayground, what a great tool! For some reason I don't get that output in my actual code, I will have to investigate further.

Comment: Ah! I have got your code working with my data, thank you. However my sample data did not demonstrate the requirement that the output should be without duplication. See an updated test that shows member 1 is repeated: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hG5WlUvdxCy I have updated my sample data in the question.

Comment: Then just change $push to $addToSet. It would avoid duplicates. https://mongoplayground.net/p/yKHtz6Dup9a

Comment: Thanks, if you update your answer, I'll accept it. The answer I posted yesterday uses addToSet and extracts just what I want (active), but your answer is elegant in providing both active and inactive in a single operation, which is probably more generally useful.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332895/mongodb-aggregate-how-to-addtoset-each-element-of-array-in-group-pipeline) shows two ways to get the result I'm looking for. The accepted answer uses push, reduce and setUnion. The newer answer is simpler, using unwind and addToSet. Both work for me but I'm going with the simpler version:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "status": "active" },
  { $unwind: "$members"},
  { $group:{
     _id: 0,
     selectedMembers: { $addToSet: '$members' }      
  }}
])
```

I'm extracting the array I want from the JSON object returned by this expression.