# how to group By date in mongodb and get top three records based on count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below Given is the structure of my collection

```
  _id                          advertisedTo    advertisedOn
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  5df72e39179e3225dc506f5b     923336749125    2019-12-14 
  5df72e39179e3225dc506f5c     923336745129    2019-12-14 
  5df72e39179e3225dc506f5d     923336749779    2019-12-14 
  5df72e57179e3225dc506f5e     923336749125    2019-12-14
  5df72e57179e3225dc506f5f     923336749330    2019-12-15
  5df72e57179e3225dc506f60     923336749335    2019-12-15
  5df73811179e3225dc506f61     923336749335    2019-12-15
  5df73811179e3225dc506f62     923336749335    2019-12-15
  5df73811179e3225dc506f63     923336749335    2019-12-15
  5df741c3179e3225dc506f65     923336742356    2019-12-15
  5df741c3179e3225dc506f66     923336739925    2019-12-15
  5df741c3179e3225dc506f67     923336725825    2019-12-15   
  5df74372179e3225dc506f69     923336014725    2019-12-16   
  5df74372179e3225dc506f6a     923336584915    2019-12-16   
  5df74372179e3225dc506f6b     923006749120    2019-12-16
```

What i want to do is get top advertisedTo numbers based on there count of last three days 
i tried below given query but its not giving me accurate result

```
 db.getCollection("advertisementhistories").aggregate([{$group:{_id:{advertisedOn:"$advertisedOn",advertisedTo:"$advertisedTo"},myCount: { $sum : 1 }}},{ $sort : { myCount : -1},{ $limit : 3 }])
```

what i want is

```
 advertisedOn    advertisedTo    myCount
 ---------------------------------------
 2019-12-14      923336749125    2
 2019-12-14      923336745129    1
 2019-12-14      923336749779    1
 2019-12-15      923336749335    4
 2019-12-15      923336742356    1
 2019-12-15      923336739925    1
 2019-12-16      923336014725    1   
 2019-12-16      923336584915    1   
 2019-12-16      923006749120    1
```

Thanks For the help

Comment: Where is the $sort in your query ?

Comment: @krishnaPrasad i have edited my query i missed it while pasting here

Answer (score 0):

You have add the `$sort` stage in your aggregation pipeline as follow:

```
db.getCollection("testCollection").aggregate([
    {
        $group:{_id:{advertisedOn:"$advertisedOn"},myCount: { $sum : 1 }}
    },
    {
        $sort: {myCount:-1}
    }, 
    { 
        $limit : 3 
    }
])
```

Output as below:

```
{ "_id" : { "advertisedOn" : "2019-12-15" }, "myCount" : 8 }
{ "_id" : { "advertisedOn" : "2019-12-14" }, "myCount" : 4 }
{ "_id" : { "advertisedOn" : "2019-12-16" }, "myCount" : 3 }
```

Comment: sir its the same query i have tried before its only giving the result of only one date i need count of top three numbers of last three days

Comment: In that case, you have removed the `advertisedTo` from groub by operation and only do the groub by `advertisedOn`

Comment: Updated the query, if you want to add the `advertisedTo` ids in array then you can check the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332895/mongodb-aggregate-how-to-addtoset-each-element-of-array-in-group-pipeline

Comment: Also you can add the `$match` operator for three days.

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.getCollection('advertisementhistories').aggregate([
          {$group:{
               _id:{advertisedTo:"$advertisedTo",advertisedOn:"$advertisedOn"},
               myCount:{$sum:1},
               advertisedTo:{$first:"$advertisedTo"},
               advertisedOn:{$first:"$advertisedOn"}}
          },
          {
               $project:{_id:0}
          },
          {
               $sort:{advertisedOn:1,myCount:-1}
          },
          {
               $group:{
                   _id:"$advertisedOn",
                   docs:{
                      $push:"$$ROOT"}
                   }
          },
          {   
                 $project:{
                     _id:0,
                     Topthree:{
                        $slice:["$docs",3]
                     }
                }
          },
          {
                $unwind:"$Topthree"
          },
          {       
                $project:{
                     advertisedTo:"$Topthree.advertisedTo",
                     advertisedOn:"$Topthree.advertisedOn",
                     myCount:"$Topthree.myCount"
                }           
          }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give the output you are looking for:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id:  { 
              on: "$advertisedOn", 
              to: "$advertisedTo" 
          }, 
          myCount: { 
              $sum: 1 
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          advertisedOn: "$_id.on", 
          myCount: 1, 
          _id: 0 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $sort: { 
          advertisedOn: 1, 
          myCount: -1  
      } 
  }
] )
```