# Project a Master Array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

My collection looks like this:

```
[{
  "_id": 1,
  "myArray": [
    "A", "B", "C"
  ]
}, {
  "_id": 2,
  "myArray": [
    "D", "E", "F"
  ]
}, {
  "_id": 3,
  "myArray": [
    "G", "H", "I"
  ]
}]
```

How do I group `myArray` so I can project an output similar to this:

```
{
  "myGroupedArray": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a distinct aggregation of an array field across indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183444/getting-a-distinct-aggregation-of-an-array-field-across-indexes)

Comment: This could potentially also answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332895/mongodb-aggregate-how-to-addtoset-each-element-of-array-in-group-pipeline

Comment: Please try to post what you have tried , as SO is a platform to help when someone is struck and not a platform to find ready made answers

Comment: Thanks @GouthamJ.M. I am new to this. Will be doing that going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      myGroupedArray: {
        $concatArrays: ["$myArray"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```